# Import build/release json export files to tfs source control through API

Tags: tfs, devops

Does TFS 2018 (or below) source control have an API method where I can import exported JSON Files (from build and release definitions) and check them in or drop them on a location in source control?

I am looking for an API because I need to do this programmatically.

Comment: Did you look at the REST API documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The APIs of "Import build/release definition json files" are equal to [Create a build definition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/definitions#create-a-build-definition) and [Create a release definition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/definitions#create-a-release-definition).

You could [get a build/release definition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/definitions#get-a-build-definition) first, and then change the build definition name and create/import it to TFS.

Regarding "check them in or drop them on a location in source control", do you mean you want to version control the JSON files? Normally, when you import the JSON file, you will get a new build definition, not a version controlled file. In future, you may use [YAML builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/build-yaml) which will configure your CI process as code, but currently, YAML build only exists in VSTS, not on-premises TFS.